# Error installing/compiling grpc on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have protobuf compiler version 3.0 and need to install grpc and grpc python plugin. Following the tutorial, I added `deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main` to my sources.list file and did `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install libgrpc-dev` which returned

```
Package libgrpc-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libgrpc-dev' has no installation candidate
```

So, I decided to compile it from source as mentioned in INSTALL notes and did:

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
 $ cd grpc
 $ git submodule update --init
 $ make 
 $ [sudo] make install
```

However, on the make step, I get

```
[MAKE]    Generating cache.mk
make: Circular /home/vagrant/grpc2/grpc/libs/opt/libboringssl.a <- /home/vagrant/grpc2/grpc/libs/opt/libboringssl.a dependency dropped.
[C]       Compiling third_party/boringssl/crypto/bio/connect.c
third_party/boringssl/crypto/bio/connect.c: In function 'split_host_and_port':
third_party/boringssl/crypto/bio/connect.c:127:17: error: declaration of 'close' shadows a global declaration [-Werror=shadow]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [/home/vagrant/grpc2/grpc/objs/opt/third_party/boringssl/crypto/bio/connect.o] Error 1
```

On switching to the release-0_11 branch, running make results in

```
[HOSTCXX] Compiling src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc
src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc:47:43: error: 'google::protobuf::compiler::csharp::GetUmbrellaClassName' has not been declared
src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc: In function 'void grpc_csharp_generator::{anonymous}::GenerateServiceDescriptorProperty(grpc::protobuf::io::Printer*, const ServiceDescriptor*)':
src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc:237:62: error: 'GetUmbrellaClassName' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [/home/vagrant/grpc2/grpc/objs/opt/src/compiler/csharp_generator.o] Error 1
```

I can't figure out how to install this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue got fixed after i made change in the file as:

```
diff --git a/src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc 

b/src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc
index 7b497df..5a8746d 100644
--- a/src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc
+++ b/src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc
@@ -44,7 +44,7 @@

 using google::protobuf::compiler::csharp::GetFileNamespace;
 using google::protobuf::compiler::csharp::GetClassName;
-using google::protobuf::compiler::csharp::GetUmbrellaClassName;
+using google::protobuf::compiler::csharp::GetReflectionClassName;
 using grpc::protobuf::FileDescriptor;
 using grpc::protobuf::Descriptor;
 using grpc::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor;
@@ -234,7 +234,7 @@ void GenerateServiceDescriptorProperty(Printer* out, const ServiceDescriptor *se
   out->Print("public static global::Google.Protobuf.Reflection.ServiceDescriptor Descriptor\n");
   out->Print("{\n");
   out->Print("  get { return $umbrella$.Descriptor.Services[$index$]; }\n",
-             "umbrella", GetUmbrellaClassName(service->file()), "index",
+             "umbrella", GetReflectionClassName(service->file()), "index",
              index.str());
   out->Print("}\n");
   out->Print("\n");
```

More specifically, please open the file `src/compiler/csharp_generator.cc` and replace all references of **GetUmbrellaClassName** by **GetReflectionClassName**

Answer (score 1):

Working backwards:

for release-0_11: it looks like you're trying to compile against the most recent protobuf. Since we're both in development right now there's occasional breakage - but grpc does track the version of protobuf it's tested against in third_party/protobuf. Try checking out and installing that version. I filed https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4697 to update to the latest protobuf 3.0 version.

for master from github: which compiler and OS are you using? I recently checked in the boringssl integration work, so it's fresh, and not nearly as battle-tested. I'd like to get it battle-tested. That said, if you do a 'make EMBED_OPENSSL=false' then things should work out for you.

for the debian package problem: I'm not sure what's going on. I'm happy to try and spin up a VM with your OS and repro if you can let me know which OS it is.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info. I'm using it on vagrant ubuntu/trusty64 so a 14.04 64bit Ubuntu with the stock compiler.